# Why does String.replaceAll() work differently in Java 8 from Java 9?

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8, java-9

Why does this code output `02` in [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) but `o2` in [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) or above?

```
"o2".replaceAll("([oO])([^[0-9-]])", "0$2")
```

Comment: A simplification of the code that still shows the behaviour : `Pattern.matches("[^[x]]", "x")` returns true with JDK8 and false with JDK9+.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Most likely due to [JDK-6609854](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6609854) and [JDK-8189343](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189343) which reported negative nested character classes handling (in your example `[^[0-9-]]`). This behavior was fixed in 9 and 10, but fix was not backported to 8. The bug for Java 8 is explained as:

> In Java, the negation does *not* apply to anything appearing in
>   nested `[brackets]`
>
> So `[^c]` does not match "c", as you would expect.
>
> **`[^[c]]` does match "c". Not what I would expect.**
>
> `[[^c]]` does not match "c"
>
> The same holds true for ranges or property expressions - if they're
>   inside brackets, a negation at an out level does not affect them.
>
> `[^a-z]` is opposite from `[^[a-z]]`

Comment: You can't prove the regex does not match the string at regex101, it does not support character class union. In PCRE, `[^[0-9-]]` matches a char that is not `[`, digit and `-` and then a `]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew removed, thanks. Would you suggest some other online tool that supports them?

Comment: In case it's not obvious -- the OP can fix this inconsistency by changing `[^[0-9-]]` to `[^0-9-]`.